# PHP regex to clear between two html tags ( nested )

Tags: php, regex, replace

I need a regex to clear everything that between two html tags. But the tags can be nested.

I wrote this

```
$theHTML = '
     <div class="holder">

        dynamic text 1

        <div class="section"> section text </div>

    </div>
';


$first='<div class="holder">';
$second='<div class="section">';
$replace  = ""; 
$find = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($first).')(.*)('.preg_quote($second).')#si', '$1'.$replace.'$3', $theHTML);
```

the output;

```
     <div class="holder"><div class="section"> section text </div>

    </div>
```

everything works fine when we have only one match. But this code can be nasted like this one;

```
$theHTML = '
     <div class="holder">

        dynamic text 1

        <div class="section"> 
            section text 

                 <div class="holder">

                    dynamic text 1

                    <div class="section"> section text </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
';
```

the output will be;

```
     <div class="holder"><div class="section"> section text </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

as you can see it removes the everything inside the first match. What i want to get;

```
     <div class="holder"><div class="section"> 
            section text 

                 <div class="holder"><div class="section"> section text </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

So the question is; how can i achieve this?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `(.*)` in the regex with `(.*?)` it will cause a *[lazy evaluation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)* which is exactly what you need

```
$theHTML = '$theHTML = '<div class="holder">
    dynamic text 1
    <div class="section"> 
        section text 
             <div class="holder">
                dynamic text 1
                <div class="section"> section text </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>';

$first='<div class="holder">';
$second='<div class="section">';
$replace  = ""; 
$find = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($first).')(.*?)('.preg_quote($second).')#si', '$1'.$replace.'$3', $theHTML);
echo $find;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<div class="holder"><div class="section"> 
            section text 
                 <div class="holder"><div class="section"> section text </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pay attention that this regex "cleans" only text that comes between `holder` to `section` and not vice verse.